# Unable to set css property of element with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I have an element in the dom that i get in a directive like this

```
angular.element.find('#id-campaign-menu')
```

all good till i try to apply some new css to it like so

```
var el = angular.element.find('#id-campaign-menu');
el.css({left: 400});
```

I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: el.css is not a function(…)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular `jQLite` object doesn't lookup through custom `element`'s and custom `selector`'s. It does look up for `nodes`/`DOM` only like `button`, `input`, `div`, etc.

If you loaded jQuery before Angular then `jQLite` API gets overrided by `jQuery` API. So you can do selector based query over DOM.

You could change your query to below for make it working with `jQLite`.

```
var campaignMenu = angular.element(document.getElementById('id-campaign-menu');
campaignMenu.css({left: 400});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's [the list of functions supported by Angular's jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angular-s-jqlite).

Note that for `.css()`:

> `css()` - Only retrieves inline-styles, does not call `getComputedStyle()`. As a setter, does not convert numbers to strings or append 'px', and also does not have automatic property prefixing.

So to support `.css()` calls that mutate the DOM, import jQuery before Angular, or use vanilla JS document selectors like `document.getElementById`.